# jQuery adding active class to navbar doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So instead of adding an active class to the navbar using HTML I instead wanted to add it through jQuery but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
$('.navbar-nav li a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
```

```html
<nav> 
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" >
      <a class="nav-link active" href="">Home</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Wat is het?</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: `location.pathname` gives you the path of the current page, eg. `/foo/bar/index.html`. None of the `href` attributes you have will match that

Comment: ijzeredraak5, what the meaning of empty links?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  var currentLoc = window.location.href;
  if(/PageYouWant/.test(currentLoc) {
    $('.navbar-nav li a').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Of course OP doesn't want this because he wants to add the class only for the link of the current page..

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for clearing that up. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Still, will not work, because it will add the class for all the links in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think what do you need is  window.location.href. 
Something like this:

```
var pathname =  window.location.href;
$('.navbar-nav li a').attr('href',pathname).addClass('active');
```

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/tbx56gtL/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set active in anchor tag you can do one of the following options.

1. Asign ids to every a tag
2. Asign a data attrib and add a class toggleClassX
3. Use $(this).addClass("active")

The following are the examples of each recomendation :

1 html:

```
<nav> 
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item" >
       <a class="nav-link active" id="myId1" href="">Home</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="myId2" href="">Wat is het?</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2 html:

```
<nav> 
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" >
      <a class="nav-link toggleClass1 active" data-tclass="1" href="">Home</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link toggleClass2" data-tclass="2" href="">Wat is het?</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

3 html: your structure is ok for the last example

1 js:

```
$("element").click(function(){
  $("#myId1").addClass("active")
});
```

2 js:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(){
  var tclass = $(this).data("tclass)
$(".toggleClass"+tclass).addClass("active")
});
```

3 js:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(){
 $(this).addClass("active")
});
```

Hope the above answer your question.